# Limit a record character length in Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following query in Access:

```
UCase(TRIM([field1]+" "+[field2]+" "+RIGHT([field3],3) AS TEST
```

The results look something like this:

```
"TEST: RICHARD ROBERT APPLESEED 112233 789"
```

What I'm wanting to do is limit the length of the first field (field1) within this query to 19 characters and if the name goes over then it starts trimming from the right side like so:

"TEST: RICHARD ROBERT APPL 112233 789"

There are records that don't go over the 19 characters and those should remain the same but for the ones that do they need to stay at 19.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `left()`:

```
LEFT(UCase(TRIM([field1] & " " & [field2] & " " & RIGHT([field3], 3), 19) AS TEST
```

Comment: Awesome that worked! Thank you! I just had to do LEFT on the first field Ucase(LEFT(TRIM([field1],19)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUBSTR :

`UCase(SUBSTR(TRIM([field1],0,19) & " " & [field2] & " " & RIGHT([field3], 3), 19) AS TEST`

EDIT:

It appears Access doesn't have SUBSTR....... sorry!

Comment: It's been fun having to find the access version of SQL syntax haha. Thanks though!